# c++ constructor trouble

Tags: c++, constructor, linker

I recently started working with c++ after a few years in other languages and I am having trouble getting code to compile with constructors. I know the problem is the constructor because if I comment it out everything works fine. I have copied some code directly from a c++ book and I am still getting errors. I am compiling in the command line with g++.
The compiler error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "GradeBook::GradeBook(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in ccoPO1iA.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

gradeBookTest.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GradeBook.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
GradeBook book1("newClass");
}
```

GradeBook.h

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class GradeBook
{
public:
GradeBook(string);
void setCourseName(string);
string getCourseName();
void displayMessage();

private:
string courseName;
};
```

GradeBook.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GradeBook.h"

using namespace std;

GradeBook::GradeBook(string name)
{
setCourseName(name);
}

void GradeBook::setCourseName( string name )
{
courseName = name;
}

string GradeBook::getCourseName()
{
return courseName;
}

void GradeBook::displayMessage()
{
cout << "this is the gradebook for\n" << getCourseName() << endl;
}
```

The indentation got messed up somehow when I copied the code into the browser...

Comment: just added, I forgot when I was posting

Comment: That's a linker error, not a compiler error. What is your command line to compile the code?

Comment: g++ -o test GradeBookTest.cpp

Comment: @Chris.Stover: And what about GradeBook.cpp? When do you link that in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile `GradeBook.cpp` as well along with `gradeBookTest.cpp`. This is happening because the compiler can see the constructor in the `.h` but come linking time, the  function definition of that constructor is nowhere to be seen.

```
g++ -o test GradeBookTest.cpp GradeBook.cpp
```

Comment: Wow...Can't believe I did that. It's been a while since I wrote any C++ :/